# What does Chrome try to tell me? (aka red dot always appears on Google Chrome without apparent reason)

Tags: notifications, chrome-for-android

For a while now, there is a permanent red dot over my Google Chrome app icon:

[image: red dot over Chrome]

I don't have any tabs open (had many, closed them all trying to get rid of the dot) and checked all possible settings of the app.

When I open the app and close the default tab it shows, the app close, dot disappears for a second then showing again.

Why is there a red dot, and how can I get rid of it?

Device and OS: realme 6 pro V2.0, android version 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the Chrome [app icon badge](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications), which is a notification alert. You should be able to access the notification details in the notification panel.

In this case, it turns out be a download complete alert,
which wasn't swiped away:

[image: download complete notification]

Comment: Thanks, worth to add a follow-up of my case, I didn't notice the notification because I have several Google accounts on the device, which aren't used frequently, and each sending notifications that I just ignore. Hence, this download complete notification was buried down the list, and I didn't notice.